# Install packages in $HOME/usr

Tags: software-installation, yum, rpm

I'm looking to script use of `rpm --relocate`. How to change the default location packages are installed to - from `user/local` to `$HOME/usr`?

Do I need to do it all manually (removing and reinstaling to a new location)?

Answer (score 2):

If the packages are already installed, yes you
have to erase and reinstall using --relocate.

The --relocate operates only during installation
(though there is no important reason that the
relocated paths could not be changed after an install,
just noone has bothered, its quite easy to erase and reinstall).